# ArrayPlot does not draw unit disk

Tags: plotting, image

I've been trying to write a program that could plot a unit circle into an image. The idea is using Arrayplot to plot the Part of pixels that fall into a disk area that radius less equal to 1.

```
img2 = N@Map[255 - Mean[#] &, 
ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}, "Data"], {2}];
{W, H} = Dimensions[img2];
i = Range[W]; j = Range[H];
xi = (2 i - W - 1)/W; yj = (2 j - H - 1)/H;  
radius = Sqrt[xi^2 + yj^2] ;(*These two lines are mapping each pixel to unit disk, just igrone the pixels fall out unit circle i.e. value less than -1 or greater than 1. *)
transimg2 = img2[[Round[Cases[radius, c_ /; -1 <= c <= 1]]]];
ArrayPlot[transimg2, Frame -> False]
```

Then got the error:

> ArrayPlot::mat: Argument {{92.3333,92.3333,90.6667,92.6667,93.6667,98.,92.,93.3333,90.3333,95.,92.,95.,101.333,93.6667,95.6667,100.333,100.667,100.,94.6667,96.6667,102.,101.667,103.333,100.333,102.,99.3333,101.333,105.667,97.6667,101.333,99.,100.667,103.333,99.6667,101.667,95.,98.3333,90.,99.,89.6667,91.6667,93.,91.6667,87.,87.3333,83.6667,86.,88.,86.6667,87.3333,<<462>>},<<49>>,<<312>>} at position 1 is not a list of lists.

Please help to give some advice what may the problem in my code, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you verify each line of code was correct before you went on to the next? That is the way to debug code like yours.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like: `With[{img=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}]},
ImageMultiply[
 img,Graphics[{White,Disk[]},Background->None,ImageSize->ImageDimensions[img]]]
]`?

Comment: How about: `ArrayPlot[DiskMatrix[100]]`

Answer (score 2):

this does more or less what you appear to be trying to do:

```
img2 = N@Map[255 - Mean[#] &, 
    ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}, "Data"], {2}];
{W, H} = Dimensions[img2];
transimg2 = 
  Outer[If[Norm[{#1, #2} - {W, H}/2] < 100, img2[[#1, #2]], 0] &, 
   Range[W], Range[H]];
ArrayPlot[transimg2]
```

[image]

this is much faster to use matrix multiplication:

```
  ArrayPlot[DiskMatrix[100, {W, H}] img2]
```

> same result

using only image functions:

```
ImageCrop@
   ColorNegate@
    ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@#, 
     Image@DiskMatrix[100, ImageDimensions@#]] &@
 ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "GrayScale"]
```

(without the twice `ColorNegate` you end up with a black background )

Comment: Thanks very much, 100 is the just the half of original image, so that it should be altered to other value. Am i right?

Comment: 100 is the radius of the circle in pixel coordinates, so use whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into an answer. Perhaps:

```
With[{img = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}], "Grayscale"]},
    ImageMultiply[
        img,
        Graphics[{White,Disk[]},Background->None]
    ]
]
```

[image]

or

```
With[{img = ImageCrop[ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}], "Grayscale"], 250]},
    ImageMultiply[
        img,
        Graphics[{White,Disk[]},Background->None]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input very much! I think the effect is similar to what I want, but I still want to let the program decides which pixels are belonging to the disk and which are not. So it could generate more precise result I think.

Comment: It is simple to control the size of the disk, for example, using `Graphics[{White, Disk[]}, PlotRange->2, Background->None]` will make the disk half the size of the image.

Comment: Also note that my approach with a `Graphics` disk produces an antialiased disk, whereas using a `DiskMatrix` disk produces a non-antialiased disk.